# Ativar o link do menu após carregar a página

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer uma comparação da página que estou carregando com todos os elementos da minha tag `a` . para que achando o elemento ele aplique a estilização. Alguém pode me ajudar com esse erro?

```js
window.onload =function(){
    
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  var lista = document.getElementById('lista');
  var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var url_atual = window.location.href;
  
  for (i=0; i<link.length; i++ ){ //tira toda formatação da tag "a"
    link[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    link[i].style.color = "";
  }
  menu.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; // altera o fundo
  menu.style.color = "#ffffff"; // altera a cor

}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body id="menu">
  <ul id="lista">
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Fotos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" >Agenda</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" >Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Tem como adicionar um exemplo executável? não entendi muito bem o que você quer

Comment: @Douglas Teles, pelo que entendi o objetivo é o elemento ancora aparecer com um estilo diferente se o endereço a que a ancora corresponder for o endereço da página.

Comment: Que comparação vc quer fazer? A pergunta não diz.

Answer (score -1):

Samuel veja se é isso que você precisa:

```
window.onload =function(){
    var lista = document.getElementById('lista');
    var link = document.querySelectorAll('#lista a');
    var url_atual = window.location.href;

    for (i=0; i<link.length; i++ ){ 
        if(url_atual == link[i].href){
            link[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
            link[i].style.color = "#ffffff"; 
        }else{
            link[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
            link[i].style.color = "";
        }
    }
}
```